# Laravel: Proyecto en Laravel no carga

Tags: laravel

Llevo dias con este problema al cargar mi proyecto en laravel lo primero es que al usar PHP ARTISAN SERVE se elimina el server.php y me salta su error, lo copio y al arrancar se vuelve a borrar. Ahora al ejecutar el comando de PHP ARTISAN SERVE el proyecto no carga no salen las lineas que normalmente salen al cargar el proyecto. Espero solucionarlo llevo dias con esto.

Comment: Deberías probarlo mejor directamente en WAMP o LAMP. Si persiste tu problema busca el proyecto de laravel en github, te descargas el zip, le pasas composer y reintentas nuevamente.

Comment: el problema es de antivirus y permisos de la computadora.